# returning an object (or a struct) in c++

Tags: c++, struct

hey, i got an question about what is going on in the next code:

```
 typedef struct {
      double re,im;
 } Complex;

 Complex ComplexCreate(double r=0.,doublei=0.)
 {
      Complex c;
      c.re=r;
      c.im=i;
      return c; // problem with this line 
      // my question is : is c getting duplicated and returning or does it return nothing
      // when i we go back to the main
 }
```

and i do know that in c++ i can and should use classes its just something that i want to understand for a test.
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: BTW, using struct isn't something **bad** in C++. struct is just a class with everything public and you can use it when you need it. The standard container std::pair is a templated struct with two fields and people use it everyday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C is going to be duplicated and you will get it. You can check it by yourself :

```
#include <iostream>


typedef struct T {
double a;
int b;
} T;


T f() {
    T newT = {10.0,5};
    std::cout << "Temporary address : " << &newT << std::endl;
    return newT;
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    T retT = f();
    std::cout << "Final address : " << &retT << std::endl;
}
```

will usually produces different addresses like :

```
Temporary address : 0x7fff97d92660
Final address : 0x7fff97d926c0
```

Answer (score 5):

When no optimization is enabled, a copy of c will be made and returned. If Named Return Value Optimization (NRVO) is available the compiler *may* elide the copy.

Beyond that, why isn't complex a class with a constructor:

```
class Complex
{
public: 
    Complex( double r = 0.0, double i = 0.0 ) 
       : re( r ) 
       , im( i )
    {}

    double re;
    double im; 
};
```

Then, if you still needed a function like Complex ComplexCreate(double r=0.,doublei=0.) it would look like:

```
Complex ComplexCreate( double r= 0.0, double i = 0.0 )
{
    return Complex( r, i );
}
```

Returning an unnamed temporary variable here means compilers without Named Return Value Optimization (NRVO) will have a better chance to elide the copy of the local object - instead, working directly on the callers stack.

Comment: You could then totally eliminate the whole ComplexCreate by doing "Complex c( r, i );" :D

Comment: @Goz... obviously yes... but I really wanted to mention the use of unnamed temporary variables, and leaving the discussion in terms of ComplexCreate() seemed to be the path of least resistence.

Answer (score 4):

It will return a `Complex` object, but it may not make a copy either due to [NRVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NRVO).

Answer (score 2):

This can help you to understand mechanism: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74a-returning-values-by-value-reference-and-address/

Answer (score 0):

Also

**Stephen C.Dewhurst "C++ Gotchas. Avoiding Problems in Coding and Design"**

Gotcha 58.